# Specify pandas index name in the constructor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Can I specify a pandas DataFrame index name in the constructor?

Said otherwise, I would like to do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]})
df.rename_axis(index='myindex', inplace=True)
```

with a single line of code (by calling only the constructor)

Comment: Chain the rename_axis without inplace to the constructor?

Comment: Why not chain the two, so `df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]}).rename_axis(index='myindex')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass an `index` to the `DataFrame` constructor with the given name that you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]}, index=pd.Index([], name='myIndex'))
df
```

```
         a  b
myIndex
0        1  3
1        2  4
```

Comment: I am receiving an error ```ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (0, 2)```.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (0)`. And for a series with existing indices, `pd.Series({"a": 1, "b": 3}, index=pd.Index([], name='myIndex'))`, the result is empty: `Series([], dtype: int64)`

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is inlining the `.rename_axis` call:

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4]}).rename_axis('myindex')
```

```
         a  b
myindex
0        1  3
1        2  4
```